# Github actions is not working when I create a release

Tags: github-actions, release

I need help. I have the an github action workflow to run when I generate a new release

```
# version 1.0
name: CI/CD - Upgrade Chart and Deploy 
on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up kubectl
        uses: matootie/dokube@v1.4.0
        with:
          personalAccessToken: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN }}
          clusterName: ######

      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get repository name
        id: repo_name
        run: echo "::set-output name=name::$(echo ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY} | cut -d'/' -f2)"

      - name: Upgrade Helm chart
        run: |
          RELEASE_NAME="${{ steps.repo_name.outputs.name }}"
          helm upgrade --install $RELEASE_NAME ./.chart/ \
            --set appVersion=${{ github.ref_name }},version=${{ github.event.release.name }}
```

The problem is that the action is not triggered either when I create or when I publish a new release.

Comment: Where did you put this file in your codebase?

Comment: Are you eventually using another workflow to create / publish the release?

Comment: This file is in .github/workflows/cd.yaml. I don't have another action that is executed when a new release is created or published

Comment: Do you create the release from the same branch where you run the action?

Comment: yes i do. :( sigue sin funcionar

Comment: And do you create the release manually, or is it created as part of another workflow?

Comment: Do you can change the release type to `published` and then create a release? And why did you choose `created` in the first place?

Comment: Is your workflow file on your repo's default branch?

Comment: In addition to @Fcmam5 comment, are you on GitHub Enterprise Server (GHES) or GitHub Enterprise Cloud (GHEC)?

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI; you can use `github.event.repository.name` to get just your repo name by itself.

From https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context for `github.event`:

> The full event webhook payload. You can access individual properties of the event using this context. This object is identical to the webhook payload of the event that triggered the workflow run, and is different for each event. The webhooks for each GitHub Actions event is linked in "Events that trigger workflows." For example, for a workflow run triggered by the push event, this object contains the contents of the push webhook payload.